# Checking last week and last to last week pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame-

```
  colA     colB      colC
0  A    2020-01-13   0.8 
1  A    2020-01-20   0.5
2  A    2020-01-27   0 
3  B    2020-01-14   0.3    
4  B    2020-01-21   0.6
5  B    2020-01-28   0
6  C    2020-01-15   0.3
7  C    2020-01-22   0.2
8  C    2020-01-29   0
```

This is a minimal example of the dataframe. The actual dataframe has colB values of a month(30 days) for each value of colA.

I want to check for the dates `2020-01-27 to 2020-01-31` if the corresponding day last week and last to last week for the conditions-

if val of col is greater than 0.5 for both the last week and last to last or any one of them
if its true print the corresponding dataframe series.

Example-

`A 2020-01-27 0` and `B 2020-01-28 0` will be the result since `A 2020-01-20` had colc value 0.5 and A `2020-01-13` has 0.8. Similarly for `B 2020-01-28 0`

My attempt-

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df['DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df["DT"])

start_date='2020-01-27'
end_date='2020-01-31'

start_date= datetime.strptime(start_date,'%Y-%m-%d')
df.loc[df['DT']==start_date+timedelta(-7) & (df['Error%']>=0.5)]
```

Comment: @Jezrael Can you help me out?

Comment: what you mean by last to last week? Which weeks you need to check? Days range for each `colaA` is 1-30?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi yes colA has range 1-30 and last to last week means for ex for the 20th last to last week would be 6th

Comment: still i don't understand `last to last week`, can you post several examples?

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi for today 2020/01/30 (Thursday) the last Thursday would be 2020/01/23 and the last to last thursday would be 2020/01/16

Comment: now i get it. `any of them` includs both of them

Answer (score 0):

Here You go:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

data = StringIO("""
colA colB colC
A 2020-01-13 0.8
A 2020-01-20 0.6
A 2020-01-27 0
B 2020-01-14 0.3
B 2020-01-21 0.6
B 2020-01-28 0
C 2020-01-15 0.3
C 2020-01-22 0.2
C 2020-01-29 0
""")

# load data into data frame
df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=' ')

# convert string to datetime
df['colB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['colB'])

# find last and second last week dates
top_date = df['colB'].max()
last_week = top_date - relativedelta(days=top_date.weekday())
second_last_week = last_week -relativedelta(days=7)

# filter rows by dates and condition
df = df[(df['colB'].isin([last_week, second_last_week])) & (df['colC'] > 0.5)]
```

**Output:**

```
  colA       colB  colC
1    A 2020-01-20   0.6
```